# ASP.NET Core 6 : server returning proper array length but empty data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am using ASP.NET Core 6. I have a controller that is returning the proper number of items in the array, however the objects themselves are empty.

ChartController.cs

```
[ApiController]
public class ChartController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("charts/{symbol:alpha}")]
    public IEnumerable<ChartDataOhlc> GetChartData(string symbol)
    {
        List<ChartDataOhlc> data = new List<ChartDataOhlc>()
        {
            new() { DateTime = DateTime.Now, Open = "1", High = "5", Low = "0", Close = "4" },
            new() { DateTime = DateTime.Now, Open = "1", High = "5", Low = "0", Close = "4" },
            new() { DateTime = DateTime.Now, Open = "1", High = "5", Low = "0", Close = "4" },
            new() { DateTime = DateTime.Now, Open = "1", High = "5", Low = "0", Close = "4" },
            new() { DateTime = DateTime.Now, Open = "1", High = "5", Low = "0", Close = "4" },
        };

        // list2.Add(new Test() { A = 1, B = "B1" });
        return (data);
    }
}
```

ChartDataOhlc.cs

```
public class ChartDataOhlc
{
    public DateTime DateTime;
    public string Open = null!;
    public string High = null!;
    public string Low = null!;
    public string Close = null!;
}
```

But all I'm getting is `[{},{},{},{},{}]`

Comment: Use {get; set;} in ChartDataOhlc.cs model. These should be properties, it will work

Comment: Hello @Bar are you still having problem with this? Do you still need any further assistance on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `ChartDataOhlc` class fields with properties like :

```
public class ChartDataOhlc
{
    public DateTime DateTime {get; set;}
    public string Open {get; set;} = null!;
    public string High {get; set;} = null!;
    public string Low {get; set;} = null!;
    public string Close {get; set;} = null!;
}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Why is this necessary? Doesn't seem obvious.

Comment: The serializer you are using doesn't serialize fields (by default) e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.includefields?view=net-6.0#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_IncludeFields